# How to apply WrapText to entite WorkSheet of EPPLUS Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am able to apply `WrapText` to columns as below

```
  ws.Cells[row, column].Style.WrapText = true;
```

How can I apply `WrapText`  to entire WorkSheet for all Rows and Columns in Excel file.

Comment: What have you tried? what problems have you had

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with a simple statement.

However, a solution that works:

```
var rowIdx = 1;
var columnIdx = 1;
while (worksheet.Cells[rowIdx, columnIdx].Value != null)
{
    while (worksheet.Cells[rowIdx, columnIdx].Value != null)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[rowIdx, columnIdx].Style.WrapText = true;
        columnIdx++;
    }
    columnIdx = 1;
    rowIdx++;
}
```

It does come with the assumption that the Worksheet has no empty cells somewhere in the middle. Of course this approach can also be taken using a nested for loop if the amount of cells and rows is known.

Answer (score 0):

Below code fixed my issue.

```
 foreach (DataColumn dc in sampleDataTable.Columns) //looping through DataTable columns
  {

   var idx = ws.Cells["1:1"].First(c => c.Value.ToString() == dc.ColumnName.ToString()).Start.Column;
   ws.Column(idx).Style.WrapText = true; // wrapping applying to entire column

  }
```